# why unity 8 not any work, Is it illusion?

Tags: unity, 16.04, desktop-environments, unity8

I was install `unity8-desktop-session-mir`.

On `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and my pc is not touch but my problems:

- for start unity I have to wait about 2 min.
- and after start I have one window only on desktop.
- I can't open terminal or any apps.
- I can't listen the music in single win in desktop sound is mute.
- & ...

I think this an very very simple sample.
I have 2 question :

> 1. Why I have this problems?
> 2. What is the solution?

Comment: Illusion?! BTW, Unity 8 is beta *for a reason*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 8 works very well on Ubuntu touch. I am writing at the moment with unity 8.
But it is in beta right now. I think it is supporting only a small range of drivers now.

If you wanna see unity 8 in action, just watch videos for example on youtube.